# AWS Rsudio Server package installation issue; cannot find -lboost_filesystem and -lboost_system

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, installation, boost, rstudio-server

I am using a Rstudio AMI developed by Louis Aslett and try to install R package requires lib boost-dev, the latest version of which is installed and there are Boost libraries installed in /usr/include/boost.  However, the package failed to be installed with a following error;

```
> install_github("velocyto-team/velocyto.R", lib="/home/rstudio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6")
Downloading GitHub repo velocyto-team/velocyto.R@master
Skipping 1 packages not available: pcaMethods
✓  checking for file ‘/tmp/RtmpqEM2ow/remotes8bb32d2c94c/velocyto-team-velocyto.R-83e6ed9/DESCRIPTION’ ...
─  preparing ‘velocyto.R’:
✓  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  cleaning src
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
─  building ‘velocyto.R_0.6.tar.gz’

* installing *source* package ‘velocyto.R’ ...
** using staged installation
** libs
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/rstudio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppArmadillo/include"  -fopenmp -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-VAQCff/r-base-3.6.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/rstudio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppArmadillo/include"  -fopenmp -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-VAQCff/r-base-3.6.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c points_within.cpp -o points_within.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/rstudio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppArmadillo/include"  -fopenmp -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-VAQCff/r-base-3.6.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c routines.cpp -o routines.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o velocyto.R.so RcppExports.o points_within.o routines.o -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lstdc++ -llapack -lblas -fopenmp -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_filesystem
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'd appreciate any workaround for this.

```
> session_info()
─ Session info ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
 os       Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS          
 system   x86_64, linux-gnu           
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  C.UTF-8                     
 ctype    C.UTF-8                     
 tz       Etc/UTC                     
 date     2020-04-03                  

─ Packages ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package     * version date       lib source        
 assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 backports     1.1.5   2019-10-02 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 BiocManager * 1.30.10 2019-11-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 callr         3.4.3   2020-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 cli           2.0.2   2020-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 curl          4.3     2019-12-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 devtools    * 2.2.2   2020-02-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 digest        0.6.25  2020-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 ellipsis      0.3.0   2019-09-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 fansi         0.4.1   2020-01-08 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 fs            1.4.0   2020-03-31 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 glue          1.3.2   2020-03-12 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 pkgbuild      1.0.6   2019-10-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 pkgload       1.0.2   2018-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 prettyunits   1.1.1   2020-01-24 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 processx      3.4.2   2020-02-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 ps            1.3.2   2020-02-13 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 R6            2.4.1   2019-11-12 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 remotes       2.1.1   2020-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 rlang         0.4.5   2020-03-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 rprojroot     1.3-2   2018-01-03 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 rstudioapi    0.11    2020-02-07 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 testthat      2.3.2   2020-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 usethis     * 1.5.1   2019-07-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 withr         2.1.2   2018-03-15 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.0)

[1] /home/rstudio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6
[2] /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
[3] /usr/lib/R/site-library
[4] /usr/lib/R/library
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`.  When you said above "Boost libraries installed in `/usr/include/boost`." you confused *headers* with *libraries*.  The command above will get you the actual libraries.

Comment: Thanks.  It worked.

Comment: Great, glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any advice on this if the error persists after `sudo apt-get install libboost-dev` is run and the newest version is installed, but the error persists?

```
$ sudo apt-get install libboost-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libboost-dev is already the newest version (1.62.0.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 80 not upgraded.
```

and still

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_filesystem
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: recipe for target 'velocyto.R.so' failed
make: *** [velocyto.R.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘velocyto.R’
```

Working on RStudio Server